# How To Split 0 Day 15 Hour 1 Min 0 Sec and assign it in different variable in java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string like this:

```
var time ="0 Day 15 Hour 1 Min 0 Sec";
```

How can I extract the numbers in the string into variables like below?

```
var day=0;
var hour=15;
var min=1;
var sec=0;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a global regular expression to match digits, then destructure immediately to put the 4 matches into 4 variables:

```js
var time ="0 Day 15 Hour 1 Min 0 Sec";
const [day, hour, min, sec] = time.match(/\d+/g);
console.log(day);
console.log(hour);
console.log(min);
console.log(sec);
```

Answer (score 1):

check out the code snippet:

```js
var time ="0 Day 15 Hour 1 Min 0 Sec";

var numericValue=[];
var textKey=[];
var result={};
time.split(" ").map((value,index)=> {
   return (
       (index+1)%2 == 0 ? 
       textKey.push(value.toLowerCase())
       : numericValue.push(Number(value))
   )
});

for(let i=0;i<textKey.length;i++){
  result[textKey[i]]=numericValue[i]
}
console.log(result);
console.log(result.day);
```